# java hide implementing class details between two layers

Tags: java, interface, implementation, decouple

I am building an application that has a business logic layer which needs to access the DAO layer for all DB related stuff. My requirement is such that the DAOImpl class can keep changing so I am looking for ways in which I can get a handle to the DAOImpl class in my business logic class without the need to know the actual DAOImpl class. Is there any way I can achieve this in Java?

Comment: Just to add to the question, at any given point of time, there will just be one DAOImpl class that would be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DAOImpl` class should implement an interface `DAOLayer` (say). You businessLogic class should be composed of a `DAOLayer` object.

```
class BusinessLogic
{
    /// ...

    DAOLayer daoLayer;

    public BusinessLogic(DAOLayer daoLayer)
    {
        this.daoLayer = daoLayer;
    }

    /// ...
}

class DAOImpl implements DAOLayer
{
    /// ...
}
```

You should pass the actual implementation of `DAOLayer` while creating `BusinessLogic` class object.

Similar to following:

```
DAOLayer aDaoLayer = new DAOImpl();
BusinessLogic bl = new BusinessLogic(aDaoLayer);
```

OR

```
    public BusinessLogic()
    {
        this.daoLayer = DAOFactory.create(true);
    }

class DAOFactory
{
    public static DAOLayer create(bool isDB)
    {
        DAOLayer aDao;

        if(isDB)
        {
            aDao = // create for DB
        }
        else
        {
            aDao = // create for file
        }

        return aDao;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this but how will the BusinessLogic constructor get a handle to the DAOImpl object. I would have to put in something like - this.daoLayer = new DAOImpl(); That will make specific to the current DAOImpl implementation.

Comment: see the edits. Within `BusinessLogic` DAO related objects should not be created. OR you can also use factory pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Your buisness logic should definetly only handle DAO [interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), that will hide actual imlementation.

To be able to quickly change implementing classes, take a look at IoC containers, such as [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html)

Answer (score 0):

sound like you want to use an [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), it is java's basic method of decoupling implementation from the desired behavior.